# Numpy converts to int32 while dividing float64 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-conversion

I have two `numpy.float64` numbers, the results of dataframe queries. Surprisingly their division gets `numpy.int32`:

```
o = data["price"].sum() / data["square"].sum()
print(type(data["price"].sum()), type(data["square"].sum()), type(o))
```

The output is:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'> <class 'numpy.float64'> <class 'numpy.int32'>
```

What's the matter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot produce...`type(numpy.float64(1)/numpy.float64(1))` returns `numpy.float64`.... not `numpy.int32`. Don't know why your's different, mind giving as an example?

Comment: Try `o = data["price"].sum() / (data["square"].sum()*1.0)` or `o = data["price"].sum() / float(data["square"].sum())`

Comment: I tried it, with previous result...

Comment: Here is a sample of csv data: 
INDEX; segment; categ; district; square; priceM; price 
1; Sell; office; Central ; 93.0 ; 86021.51; 8000000.00;
2;  Sell; office; Central; 113.0; 55752.21; 6300000.00; 
and so on

Comment: I read it by d = read_csv('somefile.csv', sep=';', delim_whitespace=False)

Comment: The delimiter in your example is not ';'. Could you show the `.head()` of your dataframe?

Comment: here is the result of data.head():  `district  square       price
132    Central   274.6  27500000.0
133      Other   108.7   2560000.0
134  New  1124.0  15000000.0
135    Central    46.0   2350000.0
136    Central    46.3   3000000.0`

Comment: Sorry, @DYZ, but I can not format that text - don't know how :(

Answer (score 0):

I was right when said, that "Numpy converts to int32 while dividing float64 numbers"! Simply it was becouse initially I worked not on a single variables, but with array created by

```
o = np.arange(len(regions))
```

(dtype of array elements are numpy.int32) and only after that it was done the following:

```
for r in regions:
    o[i] = data[data.district == r]["price"].sum() / data[data.district == r]["square"].sum()
```

As I understood, in that circumstances Numpy **converts** the result of dividing to the dtype of the array element! In spite of the fact, that the type of the result of dividing is numpy.float64...